# How to import timeseries data into an SQlite table with SQLalchemy

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am developing an app which obtains financial data from the Federal Reserve, stores it in a SQlite database using Flask-SQlalchemy, and then serves the data to my front-end dashboard (Bokeh).

The data I am using is structured as follows:

```
         date    realtime_end  realtime_start  value
0     1962-01-02   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.06
1     1962-01-03   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.03
2     1962-01-04   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   3.99
3     1962-01-05   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.02
4     1962-01-08   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.03
5     1962-01-09   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.05
6     1962-01-10   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.07
7     1962-01-11   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.08
8     1962-01-12   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.08
9     1962-01-15   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.10
10    1962-01-16   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.13
11    1962-01-17   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.12
12    1962-01-18   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.11
13    1962-01-19   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.11
14    1962-01-22   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.09
15    1962-01-23   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.11
16    1962-01-24   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.10
17    1962-01-25   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.11
18    1962-01-26   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.11
19    1962-01-29   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.12
20    1962-01-30   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.11
21    1962-01-31   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.10
22    1962-02-01   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.09
23    1962-02-02   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.08
24    1962-02-05   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.07
25    1962-02-06   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.06
26    1962-02-07   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.07
27    1962-02-08   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.07
28    1962-02-09   2018-08-02     2018-08-02   4.05
29    1962-02-12   2018-08-02     2018-08-02    NaN
```

In my SQLalchemy model, I am trying to store data from the "value" column as follows:

```
value = db.Column(db.Float())
```

It is currently in the float64 datatype, but SQLite needs it to be in a generic Python float type (rather than NumPy, which is float64). I am trying to convert the "value" column into generic Python float values as follows:

```
ValueData = GeneralData.iloc[:,3].apply(float) #slices the 'value' column from the dataframe 

ValueForSQL = Graph(value = ValueData) #stores values in the 'value' column of SQLite table.
```

I am however getting the following error when running the code: "StatementError cannot convert the series to ".

I suspect that my error is coming from this line:

```
ValueData = GeneralData.iloc[:,3].apply(float) #slices the 'value' column from the dataframe
```

Am I taking the wrong approach in converting this data series into float values?

**Edit:**

The issue appears to be that SQlite cannot process series or lists of data. If I use GeneralData['value'].iloc[3], for example, it works fine. This is because the data is already in float64 format. SQlite accepts this because it is an individual object, rather than a list or series. 'Value' is column of thousands of values, however. How can get SQlite to accept the entire series?

Comment: What is `GeneralData`? Is it a pandas dataframe?

Comment: `GeneralData['value'] = GeneralData['value'].astype(float)`?

Comment: Why don't you use `pandas.Series.astype`?

Comment: GeneralData is the name given to the pandas dataframe seen above in the data set.
GeneralData.iloc[:,3].astype(float) results in the same error message.

Comment: That wasn't what I suggested, though. Nobody has suggested `iloc`

Comment: The error is the same unfortunately when I use:

     `GeneralData['value'] = GeneralData['value'].astype(float)`

StatementError cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

Comment: Shouldn't `db.Column(db.Float()) ` be `db.Column(db.Float) `?

Comment: What does `print(GeneralData['value'].dtype)` yield? If it's really `float64` I'd be puzzled.

Comment: The issue appears to be that SQlite cannot process series or lists of data. If I use GeneralData['value'].iloc[3], for example, it works fine. This is because the data is already in float64 format. SQlite accepts this because it is an individual object, rather than a list or series. I have a column of thousands of values, however. How can get SQlite to accept the entire series?